# jQuery looping through a nested ordered list and getting the index value of each element

Tags: jquery

```
<ol id="author_list">
    <li id="author_8"><div class="author">Author 1</div>
        <ol>
            <li class="affiliation_7"><div class="affiliation">School1</div>
            </li>
            
            <li class="affiliation_8"><div class="affiliation">School2</div>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li id="author_10"><div class="author">Author 3</div>
        <ol>
            <li class="affiliation_7"><div class="affiliation">School1</div>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li id="author_9"><div class="author">Author 2</div>
        <ol>
            <li class="affiliation_8"><div class="affiliation">School2</div> 
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Which looks like this

[image]

I want to be able to loop through this list and store the exact position of the list in a json format so that I can reproduce the list in the same order later.

I'm not exactly sure how the json should look like but this is what I came up with. Not sure if this is the best way to store the data as well..

```
{
    "association1" : {
         "author": "author_8",
         "affiliation": {
             "affiliation_7": "0,0",
             "affiliation_8": "0,1"
         },
    "association2" : {
         "author": "author_10",
         "affiliation": {
             "affiliation_7": "1,0",
         },
    "association3" : {
         "author": "author_9",
         "affiliation": {
             "affiliation_8": "2,0",
         },       
}
```

My code so far

```
var indexList = [];
var level2 = $('#author_list li ol li')

level2.each(function() {
    var topIndex = $(this).index();
    var subIndex = $(this).parent().parent().index();
    indexList.push((topIndex, subIndex));    
    alert(indexList);
})
```

**UPDATE**

Just to clarify, the `0,0`, `0,1` refer to the index values of `School1` and `School2` respectively under `Author1` and so forth

Comment: what do the 0,0 and 0,1 and 1,0 represent?

Comment: Hi, updated my question. Hope its clearer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need the index values of the schools in order to reconstruct the list as you have the relative positions of the schools captured in the JSON structure.

Here's some JQuery code that will build the JSON loosely based on Imdad's schema:

```
var authors = [];
$('#author_list > li').each(function(){
  var author = {};
  author.id = $(this).attr('id').substring(7);
  author.name = $(this).find('div.author').text();

  author.schools = [];
  $(this).find('ol li').each(function(){
    var school = {};
    school.sid = $(this).attr('class').substring(12);
    school.name = $(this).find('div.affiliation').text();
    author.schools.push(school);
  });

  authors.push(author);
});

var authorsJson = JSON.stringify(authors);
console.log(authorsJson);
```

Formatted results look like:

```
[
  {
    "id":"8",
    "name":"Author 1",
    "schools":[
      {"sid":"7","name":"School1"},
      {"sid":"8","name":"School2"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":"10",
    "name":"Author 3",
    "schools":[
      {"sid":"7","name":"School1"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":"9",
    "name":"Author 2",
    "schools":[
      {"sid":"8","name":"School2"}
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: I went with your solution in the end with a tweaks. I didn't want to use the `substring` method so I added a custom attribute to the `li` of author and affiliation such that I'm doing this instead: `author.id = $(this).attr('author')`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = [];

function getList(element) {
    $.each($(element).children('li'), function() {
        var target = $(this),
            index = target.index(this) + 1,
            data = $(target).find('div.author').text(),
            eachObj = {};

        eachObj.author = data;

        if(target.has('ol')) {
            var aff = {};
            $.each($('ol li',  target), function() {
                aff[this.className] = $(this).find('div.affiliation').text();
            });     
        }
        eachObj.affiliation = aff;
        result.push(eachObj)
    });
    return result;
}

getList($('ol#author_list'));
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Zsa42/1/)***

Answer (score 1):

Its simple. The way you display it is the way it should be stored. And Keeping Ids separate makes it more flexible.

```
[
{
 "author": { "id":8, "name":"Author 3"},
 "schools":[ {"affilication":7,      "school":"School 1"},
             {"affilication":8,      "school":"School 2"}
           ]
},
{
 "author": { "id":10, "name":"Author 3"},
 "schools":[ {"affilication":7,      "school":"School 1"}     ]
},
{
 "author": { "id":9, "name":"Author 2"},
 "schools":[ {"affilication":8,      "school":"School 2"}     ]
}
]
```